# TGA loader: reverse y-axis

Tags: opengl, textures

I've written a TGA image loader in Java which is working perfectly for files created with GIMP as long as they are saved with the option `origin` set to `Top Left` (actually TGA files are meant to be stored upside down - `Bottom Left` in GIMP). My problem is that I want my image loader to be capable of reading all different kinds of TGA, so my question is: How do I flip the image upside down?

Note that I store all image data inside a one-dimensional byte array, because OpenGL (`glTexImage2D` to be specific) requires it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the size of the image, then you can write a converter which takes the byte array and the dimensions and just returns a rearranged array.  The basic idea is that you need to take each row of pixels and swap them with the row mirrored across the plane that you're flipping on.  Pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
in: bArray, width, height
out: flipArray
currentChunkIndex = 0
flipArray = allocate byte array of size width*height
for each chunk of bArray from currentChunkIndex to (width*height - width) spanning width bytes:
    copy chunk opposite to plane of reflection into flipArray
    for a vertical flip:
    take chunk of bArray starting at index ((width*height) - ((currentChunkIndex+1)*width)) and spanning width bytes,
    and copy it into flipArray at index currentChunkIndex spanning width bytes
    currentChunkIndex += width
```

Happy coding!